# Why is light reflection in glass different in the viewport than in the rendered image?

Tags: rendering, light

just a quick question.  When I do a viewport render, I like the reflection I have on glass (picture 1).  However when I do a final render, I get a really weird looking reflection (picture 2).  I'm not using any lamps or area lights, just planes set with emissions.  Anyone know why and can offer any advise?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if there's an emission plane hidden in viewport but renderable. Note also that view angle between 2 renders doesn't match a bit

Comment: Ahh i figured it out, my geometry had a dip in it which was causing that weird shape in the reflection

Comment: Also check that the number of subdivisions is the same for preview and render.